# Trying to read values from an XML file

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

Trying to read each individual address value in each endpoint element and display each individual one in a seperate textbox.

```
<client>  
  <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:" />
  <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:" />
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://127.0.0.1:" />
</client>
```

I can read the XML data and display only the value of the last element. This is actually my first try at developing anything in C#.

Here is a bit of the code I have written:

```
        XmlReader ReadFile = XmlReader.Create(AgentConfig.FileName);
        while (ReadFile.Read())
        {
            if ((ReadFile.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (ReadFile.Name == "endpoint"))
            {
                if (ReadFile.HasAttributes)
                {
                    textBox2.Text = ReadFile.GetAttribute("address");
                    textBox3.Text = ReadFile.GetAttribute("address");
                }
            }
        }
```

In the meantime I will be looking for an answer on my own, but any input would definitely be appreciated! :)

Comment: I recommend looking into XDocument and Linq to Xml

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely read up on that.

Answer (score 3):

Using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) is more convenient for your case:

```
 var addresses = XDocument.Load(AgentConfig.FileName)
                          .Descendants("endpoint")
                          .Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("address"))
                          .ToList();
```

The result is the `List<string>`, so, you can assign into your TextBoxes simply by index:

```
textBox1.Text = addresses[0];
textBox2.Text = addresses[1];
textBox3.Text = addresses[2];
```

Comment: Another question, if you do not mind -- How would I go about saving the data to the original XML file?

Comment: @bitbreaker: it's better you can ask another question in detail instead of answering in comments

Comment: I have started a new questing in regards to that matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I can read the XML data and display only the value of the last element.

You are facing this behaviour because you are overwriting your own values. If you want to append you need to change it like this

```
StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();  //before while loop
StringBuilder sb1  = new StringBuilder();  //before while loop
XmlReader ReadFile = XmlReader.Create(AgentConfig.FileName);
    while (ReadFile.Read())
    {
        if ((ReadFile.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (ReadFile.Name == "endpoint"))
        {
            if (ReadFile.HasAttributes)
            {
                sb.Append(ReadFile.GetAttribute("address") + " ");
                sb1.Append(ReadFile.GetAttribute("address") + " ");

            }
        }
    }

//Then after your loop
textBox2.Text  = sb.ToString();
textBox3.Text  = sb1.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add address Attributes to a List and finally set the text box like below

```
List<string> addresses = new List<string>();
XmlReader ReadFile = XmlReader.Create(AgentConfig.FileName);
while (ReadFile.Read())
{
    if ((ReadFile.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (ReadFile.Name == "endpoint"))
    {
        if (ReadFile.HasAttributes)
        {
            addresses.Add(ReadFile.GetAttribute("address"));
        }
    }
}
if (addresses.Count >0)
{
    textBox1.Text = addresses[0];
}
if (addresses.Count >= 1)
{
    textBox2.Text = addresses[1];
}
```